# Function ordering properly working?

Tags: javascript, html, css, function

I am new to HTML/CSS/JS and not understanding properly or am missing something completely. I am trying to update the Variable of "CitizenCost" by using Math.pow(2, NumCitizens) that part is working. The part that I am having trouble with is updating CitizenCost to the correct number and having the HTML represent it with the correct number. Right now it updates but it's always behind

IE: it should be X = 2^1 then X = 2^2 So on and so forth

However in the HTML it doesn't update accordingly it is always behind one equation so if the real cost is X = 2^2. The text will show X = 2^1. Unless the Player clicks the button again.

```
function buycitizen(){
    CitizenCost = Math.pow(2, NumCitizens);
    document.getElementById("CitizenCost").innerHTML = "Cost of Citizen " + CitizenCost;
    if(land >= CitizenCost){
        land = land - CitizenCost;
        eps = eps + 2;
        NumCitizens++;
        document.getElementById("NumCitizens").innerHTML = NumCitizens;
    }
    else
        document.getElementById("SystemMessage").innerHTML = "You do not have enough Land Resources to provide for more Citizens right now!";
    setTimeout(systemclear, 5000)}
```

Here is a fiddle demonstrating the issue

https://jsfiddle.net/Traberjkt/yaq0rbad/

Here is the Git

https://github.com/Traberjkt/Conquest

I have tried setting a timer so the text of CitizenCost updates every second. I have thought and tried putting the cost equation in a separate function and re-locating it somewhere else in the function. Sadly I have had no luck figuring this out. Any help or pointing me in the right direction would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Well, your code updates the citizen cost field, and *then* it increments the number of citizens. It should update the HTML for the cost at the same time it updates the citizen count.

Comment: That makes sense! How would I go about triggering them on the same line? Would it be best to then make a separate function that executes those 2 things and then call the function when the onclick happens?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you should make a new function called `moreCitizens(howMany)`:

```
function moreCitizens(howMany) {
  NumCitizens += howMany;
  document.getElementById("NumCitizens").innerHTML = NumCitizens;
  CitizenCost = Math.pow(2, NumCitizens);
  document.getElementById("CitizenCost").innerHTML = "Cost of Citizen " + CitizenCost;
}
```

Then instead of

```
  NumCitizens++;
```

you can just write

```
  moreCitizens(1);
```

and that will update the cost and count fields.

Comment: Alright just left on mobile right now should be back in 10-20 but I will try it out thanks a ton!

Comment: Sorry about the late response got everything working thank you! marked as solved